# Can't get a CCPointArray to work in Cocos2D-x

Tags: arrays, point, cocos2d-x

I want to create a an array of points (_grid). However, I can't seem to use this CCPointArray anywhere except the function it's created in. I've tried making it public in my class and declaring it in my header, but all fail. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after

```
CCPointArray* p = CCPointArray::create(8);
```

did you call

```
p->retain();
```

?

and remember to release it in your destructor or onExit();

in your YOUR_CLASS.h file

```
class YOUR_CLASS : public cocos2d::CCLayer {
    CCPointArray* p;
public:
    CREATE_FUNC(YOUR_CLASS);
    bool init();
    void onExit();
}
```

in your YOUR_CLASS.cpp file

```
bool YOUR_CLASS::init(){
    if(CCLayer::init()){
         p = CCPointArray::create(8);
         p->retain();
         return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void YOUR_CLASS::onExit(){
    CCLayer::onExit();
    p->release();
    p = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Oh silly me. Thank you very much. Where can I find "onExit()"?

Comment: @DavidSmall you should overwrite the super class virtual onExit() function in your own class and in your own onExit(), remember to call YOU_SUPER_CLASS::onExit()

Comment: @DavidSmall if your class is not an subclass of cocos2d node class, just call release() in your destructor.

Comment: @m.ding - for my knowledge .. how do we release the local pointer in destructor which is retain like above ..?? i mean say if p is local in some function then how will I release it in destructor ??

Comment: @user1201239 actually you can't. so you need to put it into the .h file to keep an reference to that address in the class instance.

Comment: Forgive me, but I am still a beginner. I do not understand what to do still.

Comment: @m.ding Thank you. I await your answer.

Comment: @DavidSmall sorry I forgot it after I finish my work yesterday, here it is.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you very much sir! You've been a great help!