# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 655 (Thread-77)

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I'm developing an application for Android using cocos2d-x. I'm new to cocos2d-x and C++ and I'm on windows, I have followed due process from creating the Cocos2d-x project template for Eclipse to importing the project into Eclipse and adding c++ features to it etc... I succesfully got my app to run in the emulator(target API 4.1) and it gives me the cocos2d "HelloWorld Splash" as expected. Problem is, now I'm trying to change my Application background image. I added an image in the assets directory and changed the code in "HelloWorldScene.cpp" that creates the default HelloWorld Sprite

from:

```
CCSprite* pSprite = CCSprite::create("HelloWorld.png");
```

to:

```
CCSprite* pSprite = CCSprite::create("background.jpg");
```

Once I do the latter, my emulator crashes after trying to run the App and in logcat I get the error "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)", but if I put back the default HelloWorld.png it runs again smoothly in the emulator.

I use cocos2d-2.0-rc2-x-2.0.1 and android-ndk-r8b. This App runs only on a 4.1 API device emulator, I can't get it to run on 2.3.3 and 4.3 as it crashes while trying to run. Please, kindly help me out please

Comment: Being strictly obvious, you are trying to read from a `NULL` pointer. Perhaps your `CCSprite::create` is failing to load the file and returning a `NULL` pointer and you are not checking that properly.

Comment: But I do have background.jpg file in assets directory. Why would it return NULL?  Pls is there anything else I have to do in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might forget to run the build_native.sh script to update the libgame.so

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @AshwiniAgarwal I have edit my post according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16157861/couldnt-load-game-findlibrary-returned-null-with-cocos2d-x-no-success-despit/16158059#16158059 but I still don't agree with your comment. sometimes asking questions to author did help them think and revise their post and might help them find the answer by themselves. I don't care if the "Answer" must be a sentence ends with a full stop or question mark as long as it might help the author, I will still give it a try.

Comment: @AshwiniAgarwal evidence that a question might help the author http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999771/cant-get-a-ccpointarray-to-work-in-cocos2d-x/13004332#13004332 the primary goal of stackoverflow is helping others, as long as it is not using offensive language, not restriction like "an answer cannot be a question because it doesn't provide an real answer". at least a question helps others to think.

Comment: @m.ding how do you mean "run the build_native.sh script to update the libgame.so", please how do I do that?

Comment: @degee what cocos2d-x did is, it compiles your c++ code to a java library first, and put it into the libs/arm-v7s folder, then it use the eclipse build to build this library with assets together to the apk file. once you edit the c++ file, you have to rebuild the libgame.so. There should be a script sits in android project folder named build_native.sh, you can run it using cygwin(windows) or just run it under Mac. this script will rebuild the source code to library and update assets folder according to whatever you put in the Resources folder.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's it! That was the problem, you hit the nail right on the head. I appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

- Stick to png image format.
- Make sure that your image is copied to
  assets directory on android project.(This happens automatically if
  you have the image in Resources directory).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have converted the image to png and it's in the assets directory. But the same error occurs

Answer (score 1):

Try troubleshooting your image.

- Take the "HelloWorld.png" and modify it in whatever image editor you use. If it works then you know it's not your editor.
- Try making your background image the same size as "HelloWorld.png" and in PNG format with the same default settings as "HelloWorld.png"

Also ensure that the "HelloWorld.png" is in your Assets directory, if not you may need to add the Assets directory to the search path via CCFileUtils

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks. I actually thought of, and tried this, though not all you said. Let me look at it again. By the way, What do you mean "add the Assets directory to the search path via CCFileUtils?" How do I implement this in code?

Comment: you can set or add search paths that cocos will set for its resource directory.  e.g. for win32 it would be CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->addSearchPath("../../Assets")  This should be set by default however. And if helloworld.png is in the Assets folder then it is already set. Edit: I See the question is answered, I am working on win32 and don't build for android myself.